# How do I do dynamic template manipulation in an AngularJS directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm just getting started on Angular and am trying to wrap my head around proper directive use.  I'm writing a custom directive that takes an object array and parses it into a variable number of vertical divs.  It's basically a grid system where the elements are arranged into stacked vertical columns rather than in rows.  The number of divs dynamically varies with the width of the screen, requiring dynamic changes in the div class as well as reconstructing the ordering of the array elements in the div columns as the page resizes.

When I use the contents of the template as plain, static HTML, everything loads just fine.  The filters dynamically change the dataset when you use the input fields, etc.

When I use my directive, the initial page-load looks fine.  However, dynamic filtering is broken - it is no longer bound to the input fields.  More importantly, on a page resize, the HTML fails to compile at all, leaving a blank screen and uncompiled directive tags in the DOM.

I don't know Angular well enough to troubleshoot this.  If I had to guess, it sounds like something is not being bound properly on the page $compile due to a problem with scope.

Note: I know doing string concat for the template is poor practice but I just want to get things working before I start messing around with nesting directives.

Edit: here's a link to the Github repo for my front-end code: https://github.com/danheidel/education-video.net/tree/master/site

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="channelListController">
  Creator: <input ng-model="query.creators">
  Tags: <input ng-model="query.tags">
  query: {{query}}
  <div id="channel-view">
    <channel-drawers channels="channels"></channel-drawers>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
.controller('channelListController', function ($scope, $http){
  $http.get('api/v1/channels').success(function(data){
    $scope.channels = data;
  });
})
.directive('channelDrawers', function($window, $compile){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      channels: '='
    },
    controller: 'channelListController',
    //templateUrl: 'drawer.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attr){
      scope.breakpoints = [
        {width: 0, columns: 1},
        {width: 510, columns: 2},
        {width: 850, columns: 3},
        {width: 1190, columns: 4},
        {width: 1530, columns: 5}
      ];

      angular.element($window).bind('resize', setWindowSize);
      setWindowSize();  //call on init

      function setWindowSize(){
        scope.windowSize = $window.innerWidth;
        console.log(scope.windowSize);
        _.forEach(scope.breakpoints, function(point){
          if(point.width <= scope.windowSize){
            scope.columns = point.columns;
          }
        });
        var tempHtml = '';
        for(var rep=0;rep<scope.columns;rep++){
          tempHtml +=
          '<div class="cabinet' + scope.columns + '">' +
            '<div class="drawer" ng-class="{' + ((rep%2 === 0)?'even: $even, odd: $odd':'even: $odd, odd:$even') + '}" ng-repeat="channel in channels | looseCreatorComparator : query.creators | looseTagComparator : query.tags | modulusFilter : ' + scope.columns + ' : ' + rep + '">' +
              '<ng-include src="\'drawer.html\'"></ng-include>' +
            '</div>' +
          '</div>';
        }
        console.log(tempHtml);
        element.html(tempHtml);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      }
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: Got a jsFiddle you can wire up for a test?

Answer (score 1):

The $compile function should be implemented when you want to manipulate your template. The link function should be implemented when you want to bind your template to your scope and/or setup any watchers.  If you have dynamic HTML that you're inserting into your DOM, then ask your self these questions:

1. Are you modifying the template? If so, then create an element template (angular.element(...)) and append it to your element parameter.
2. Have you modified the template (step 1) and your template contains binding expressions, interpolation expressions, and/or attributes that should bind from other templates? If so, you need to compile and link your element you created from step 1.

Here is an example:

```
      .directive('myDirective',function($compile) {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: '=',
            compile: function(element, attr) {
                  // manipulating template?
                  var e = angular.element('<div ng-model="person">{{person.name}}</div>');
                  element.append(e);

                  // the following is your linking function
                  return function(scope, element, attr) {
                       // template contains binding expressions? Yes
                       $compile(e)(scope);
                  };
            }
      });
```

To fix your code, try moving the template manipulation to your compile function, and in your linking function, call $compile(e)(scope).

Comment: This seems to be mostly working but I'm having one holdup.  I'm replacing the template on each iteration rather than appending.  However, when I try to use element.replacewith, it errs out since the new element has no valid parentNode.  Any idea on how to get around this?

Comment: In your compile function: var e = angular.element(...); element.after(e).remove(); - I am assuming that you have jQuery

Comment: That still doesn't work - after() is also looking for a parent node to append the elements to.

Comment: Without more information, i'm not sure how to help. Could you post a Plunker or Jsfiddle?

Comment: I spent about 2 hours this morning trying to get my code to work in both Plunker and JSFiddle with no luck.  I made more progress in JSFiddle but am stuck trying to figure out how to load template files there.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Wt5LJ/5/  It's not entirely working and doesn't reproduce all the issues I'm having but after spending half the morning trying to coax JSFiddle into loading my NG-include template file and serve up a stub for my AJAX calls, I need to walk away from the computer before I punch a hole in something.

Comment: I added a link to the github repo since JSFiddle is being such a pain.

Comment: compile function operates on the template, which may not have a parent.  Try moving the element.after(tempElement).remove(); code in your link function

Comment: It has occured to me that I'm doing this quite wrong.  I'm defining setWindowSize inside compile but calling it from the event handler.  That preserves the compile scope but there no reason to think that the returned function is actually getting called via link.  It would make more sense to have setWindowSize that lives on $scope which calculates the number of columns and then programatically triggers the compile/link functions.  I'm not sure how to do that though...

Answer (score 1):

First, thanks to pixelbits and pfooti for their input.  It put me on the right track.  However, I wanted the answer to be a clean slate since our discussions got into technical matters that ended up being tangential to the actual answer.

Basically, this question is poorly framed.  After doing more reading, it became clear that I was using the Angular elements in ways they aren't really intended for.

In this case, I'm doing a bunch of model manipulation in my directive and it really should occur in the controller instead.  I ended up doing that and also moving the window resize handler code to another component.

Now, I don't even need a directive to properly format my data.  A couple of nested ng-repeats with a dusting of ng-class and ng-style do the job just fine in 2 lines of HTML.

```
<div ng-repeat="modColumn in splitChannels"
  ng-class="{'col-even' : !$even, 'col-odd' : !$odd}"
  ng-style="{ width: 99 / windowAttr.columns + '%' }"
  class="cabinet">
  <div ng-repeat="channel in modColumn"
    ng-class="{'row-even' : !$even, 'row-odd' : !$odd}"
    ng-cloak
    class="panel roundnborder">
    <ng-include src="'panel.html'"></ng-include>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I could give a bit of advice from one Angular beginner to another, it would be this: if your code is getting complex or you're digging into the internals of things, step back and rethink how you're using the Angular components.  You're probably doing an action that should be done in another component class.  Proper Angular code tends to be very terse, modular and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're doing it with templates?

Can't you bind the number of columns to a variable on the scope? I've done similar stuff with just fiddling around with either ng-if directives to hide stuff that's not important now, or to have general layout stuff attached to the current scope (I generally stuff it all into properties on $scope.view)

There's also plenty of this kind of stuff that already works in css3's media selectors as well, without needing mess with the DOM at all. Without a clearer picture of what you're trying to accomplish I'm not sure if this is super-necessary. More than one ways to skin a cat, etc etc.

Otherwise, @pixelbits is right - if you are fiddling with the DOM tree directly, that needs to happen in compile - values going into the DOM goes into link.

Comment: As the example stands right now, you are correct, I could do it with CSS3 media selectors.  In fact, I was doing that earlier and it worked quite well.  However, I plan to make the behavior more complex.  For example, I would like the column number breakpoints to have a bit of hysteresis so that you have to go a certain distance past the breakpoint to trigger it.  I'm not certain that's even possible in CSS. As for binding the number of columns to the main scope, I think that's probably the way to go.  However, I'm not sure how I can trigger the compile/link functions from an event handler.